# How to disable future dates in datepicker using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Datepicker future dates not disable. Here is my code for datepicker in HTML

```
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" style="width: 106px; height: 30px;" type="text" id="nodate" value="<?php echo date('m-j-Y');?>"  readonly=""/>
        <div class="input-group-addon add-on" style="width: 35px; height: 25px;"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></div>
        &emsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/attendance/noRecordDate/';?>'+ $('#nodate').val()">Add Attendance</button>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#nodate" ).datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **[maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)**
>
> Multiple types
> supported:
>
> ```
> Date: A date object containing the maximum date.
> Number: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
> String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.
> ```

so you need to either set the date object properly , or simply set as string or number as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#nodate" ).datepicker({  maxDate: '0' });
});
</script>
```

Comment: quote it as follows: `{  maxDate: '0' }`

Comment: I mean I use your code exactly, but it is not working.

Comment: please make sure that your browser does not caching js , CTRL+F5 to reload your js files

Comment: I did not put in js file. I only put in my head html.

Comment: works like a charm ! https://jsfiddle.net/9v7f7r0p/ , PS i had to set the date value statically as long as jsfiddle doesn't parse php;

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: ?? check out the jsfiddle link

Comment: What if the date is not statically set?

Comment: it will be the same, jsfiddle is a website to test client side scripts, and php is a server side language, so i only removed the php part to be able to test it, with php on my local machine works fine too

Comment: what's the output ? and check your console for any errors

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dbDate = "2017-03-24";
    var date2 = new Date(dbDate);

    $( "#nodate" ).datepicker({ 
    
      
     dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
     maxDate: new Date()
    
    }).datepicker('setDate', date2);

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="input-group input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" style="width: 106px; height: 30px;" type="text" id="nodate" value=""  readonly=""/>
        <div class="input-group-addon add-on" style="width: 35px; height: 25px;"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></div>
        &emsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/attendance/noRecordDate/';?>'+ $('#nodate').val()">Add Attendance</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for mine, my datepicker btw is from bootstrap.

Comment: If error in javascript file then all function will not work or if you add javascript source file more than one then it will not working