# Disabling future dates in a jQuery UI date-picker-month , isn't disabling future years

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

First of all, I've discard the following similar questions:

[Disable future dates in jQuery UI Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002781/disable-future-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker/4002792)

[Disable future dates after today in Jquery Ui Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006328/disable-future-dates-after-today-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

[Disable Months On Month/DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945935/disable-months-on-month-datepicker)

I have the following date-picker-month (I'm using: jQuery UI Datepicker 1.11.4.
):

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class='input-group date' >
        <input 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control date-picker-month disabled" 
            id="datePickerMonth" 
            value="{{ mes_actual|date:"m/Y" }}" 
            autocomplete="off"
        >
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it looks like this:

[image: years]
[image: months]

**I just want to disable the selection of future years**. If I add the `maxDate` property (which is the suggested answer in many similar questions) like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datePickerMonth").datepicker({
     maxDate: new Date() // the same with maxDate: 0
  });

});
```

Then I can select:

1. Years: a future year (**I want to disable future years**)
2. Months: of the selected year
3. Days: it display days until the current date but, if I select one of these days, the selected day becomes in the year, **even if I previously selected a future year**

[image]
[image]

I tried with this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#descuentos_hasta").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (){
      return [false, ''],
    },
  });

});
```

But I get the same result as if I hadn't used it: I still can select future years and months.

I hope to achieve something like this:

[image]

Where years in gray circle were been disable, and the same thing with the future months,

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017024/how-to-disable-future-dates-in-datepicker-using-jquery) is close, but I get the same behaviour that I described related with the days and my datepicker is only with years-months.

Please, any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATED: SOLVED**

**I apologize, I tried to decrease all the unnecessary stuff and I finally found the js file, where the  `maxDate: new Date()` line worked. I added the snippet below for anyone else.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link media="all"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.49/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class='input-group date' >
          <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker-month disabled" name="datePickerMonth" id="datePickerMonth"  }}" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.49/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    
</body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      if (  $('.date-picker-month')[0]){
        $('.date-picker-month').datetimepicker({
          //format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
          viewMode: 'years',
          format: 'MM/YYYY',
          widgetPositioning: { horizontal: 'auto',  vertical: 'auto'},
          maxDate: new Date()
        });
      }  
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet please. It will be easy t debug.

Comment: I apologize, I tried to decrease all the unnecessary files and I finally found the js file, where the  maxDate: new Date() line worked. I added the snippet below for anyone else